# "Warning: can only update a mounted or mounting component" while using Modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I would like to use two modal in the same page as I push a button on my screen. They should show and hide sequentially. First, I need to show `isModalVisibleConnection` modal and then it should be closed and another modal(`isModalVisible` modal) should be shown. Finally, `isModalVisible` modal also should close and the App should be redirected to another screen. My code is as below for the button:

```
  onPress() {
      this.setState({ isModalVisibleConnection: true ,isModalVisibleMain: true});

      LIB.requestAccess().then((response) => {
        console.log("responsexxxx exit part",response);
        if(response.requestCode==1)
          {
            this.setState({ isModalVisibleConnection: false , isModalVisible: true});

              //////Wait for 10 seconds and Redirecting
              if(this.timer > 0) return;
              this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
                //turn off the pop up

                this.props.navigation.navigate('ParkInBuilding', {user: this.state.passedProps.user,  positionState:this.state.passedProps.positionState, parkingState: this.state.passedProps.parkingState, activeSection: 'ParkNewError_0'});
                this.timer = null;  //not necessary if you are unmounting the component
              }, 10000);
            }
            else {

              console.log("something wrong!!",response.requestMessage);

              Alert.alert(
                  'Error',
                  response.requestMessage ,

                  [
                    //{text: 'Ask me later', onPress: () => console.log('Ask me later pressed')},
                    {text: 'OK', onPress: () => this.setState({ isModalVisibleMain: false, isModalVisible: false, isModalVisibleConnection: false })},
                    //{text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
                  ],
                    { cancelable: false }
                 )
            }
            console.log("responesssssssssss Exit",response);
          });

        }
```

In the render mode I use the following pattern to put the modals:

```
  <Modal isVisible={this.state.isModalVisibleMain}>
              <Modal isVisible={this.state.isModalVisible}>
                  <View style={styles.timerContainer}>
                  <Text style={styles.orangeTextBold}>Si prega di passare il{"\n"} cancello di uscita.{"\n"}
                  <Text style={styles.itemBold}>{"\n"} </Text>
                  <Text style={styles.itemBold}>Arrivederci e grazie per aver utilizzato il nostro servizio.{"\n"}
                  </Text> </Text>
                  <Text style={styles.itemBold}> </Text>
                  <CountdownCircle
                    seconds={10}
                    radius={40}
                    borderWidth={8}
                    color="#FABB00"
                    bgColor="#fff"
                    textStyle={{ fontSize: 30 }}
                    onTimeElapsed={() => console.log('Elapsed!')}
                  />
                    </View>
                  </Modal>

                  <View isVisible={this.state.isModalVisibleConnection}>
                    <View style={styles.loader}>
                    <Text style={styles.ComOrangeTextBold}>{I18n.t('Comunicazione')}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.ComOrangeTextBold}></Text>
                    <View>
                      <Bars size={30} color="#FABB00" />
                    </View>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                </Modal>
```

I have a main modal(`isModalVisibleMain`) that the other modals are inside it. Also the second modal is inside it as a view. I should mention that, when I use the modal in a different way (put the modal separately) the second modal doesn't show in IOS. It was the only way that the app shows both modal in a proper way. 
The problem is that, as I redirect to the next screen, it shows me the following warning:

> warning: can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually
>   means you called set state, replace state or force update on an
>   unmounted component ...

An it cause lock my app some times. Do you have any idea that how can I handle this waring? (If you need any more code or information just mention it under the post. Thanks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setState actions are asynchronous and are batched for performance gains.

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value. There is no
>   guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may
>   be batched for performance gains.

In your case you may want to be certain that your navigation job will be trigger at the end of your setState :

this.setState({ isModalVisible: false }, () = > this.props.navigation.navigate(...));